# Finding the Taylor Series for a complicated function

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

Is there some trick to find the Taylor Series for this function or is the only to do it is just to differentiate .. ?

$\biggr(\sqrt{1+x^2} \cdot \cos(\sin x)\biggr)^{\frac{1}{\sin^6x}-\frac{1}{x^6}}$

Comment: the power is: $\frac{1}{sin^6x} - \frac{1}{x^6}$
just couldn't get it to be shown properly, didn't know how to fix it

Comment: I've fixed your exponent. Take a look -- in general, curly braces are used to make groupings in latex.

Comment: Thank you!  that's perfect.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, there are no tricks in mathematics. You know the drill, or you don't. But I wouldn't recommend derivatives at $x=0$, that would end in an overdose of l'Hospital. And what do you mean by "find the Taylor Series"? You don't really think there's a formula for the coefficients, do you?!

Comment: I don't know, I'm supposed to fund the limit for that as x approaches 0
thought the taylor series can help ..

Comment: I probably should have , you're right .. could you please post the details for the answer? would be really nice of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Taylor expansion can help, and I think that's *always* superior to l'Hospital, especially since people rarely think about when that's applicable at all. So we have $$\sin x=x-x^3/6+O(x^5),$$ and thus
$$\cos(\sin x)=1-x^2/2+5x^4/24+O(x^6).$$ Since $$\sqrt{1+x^2}=1+x^2/2-x^4/8+O(x^6),$$ we see that $$\sqrt{1+x^2}\,\cos(\sin x)=1-x^4/6+O(x^6).$$ Concerning the exponent: $$\frac{x}{\sin x}=1+x^2/6+O(x^4),$$ so
$$\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)^6=1+x^2+O(x^4)$$ and $$\frac{1}{\sin^6x} - \frac{1}{x^6}=x^{-4}(1+O(x^2)).$$ That means that the limit of your expression as $x\to0$ is the same as $$\lim_{x\to0}(1-x^4/6)^{x^{-4}}=e^{-1/6}.$$ In a deleted comment I wrote $e^{-1/4}$, but that was an error, sorry. :)

Answer (score 0):

No Taylor, no Hospital.
Take the log to get
$$\left(\frac{1}{\sin^6 x}-\frac{1}{x^6}\right)\ln (\sqrt{1+x^2}\cos(\sin(x)))$$

Now
$$\left(\frac{1}{\sin^6 x}-\frac{1}{x^6}\right)=\frac{x^6-\sin^6x}{x^6\sin^6 x}=\frac{x^6}{\sin^6x}\frac{x^6-\sin^6x}{x^{12}}$$
And as $\frac{x^6}{\sin^6x}\to 1$ we can forget this factor.

Further

$$\frac{x^6-\sin^6x}{x^8}=\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}\frac{x^2-x\sin x +x^2}{x^2}\frac{x^2+x\sin x +x^2}{x^2}\frac{x+\sin x}{x}$$
$$\to \frac{1}{6}\cdot 1\cdot 3 \cdot 2=1$$ So we can forget this also.

As $\frac{\ln(1+a)}{a}\to 1$ the problem reduces to
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^4}\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}\cos(\sin x)-1\right)$$
This is where it gets tricky.
Consider now
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x^2}\cos(\sin x)-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$
$$=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cos(\sin x)+\frac{1}{x^2}\left(\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\cos(\sin x)-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

As $\cos(\sin x)=1$ when $x=0$ we ignore it also and evaluate first

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)=-\frac{1}{8}$$

Leaving us with
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2}\left(\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\cos(\sin x)-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$
to evaluate. Which can be done similarly, but no one really cares.